# Can a permutation test be used on time series to quantify an effect of the marketing campaign?

Tags: time-series, hypothesis-testing, permutation-test

I am trying to accept or reject a hypothesis that a marketing campaign had positive effect on sales of some product. I am working with time series of monthly sales. The series is not stationary (it has positive linear trend).

I would like to use permutation test as I find it simpler to explain in comparison with t-test, however I wonder if my approach below is correct:

1. Remove the trend from the series and make it stationary.
2. State the significance level $\alpha = 0.05 $
3. $\mu_b=$ mean of sales before campaign

   $\mu_a=$ mean of sales after campaign
4. State the null hypothesis $H_0: \mu_a - \mu_b = 0 $
5. State the alternative hypothesis $H_a: \mu_a - \mu_b > 0 $
6. Compute empirical difference of means: $\mu_e = \mu_a - \mu_b $
7. Generate large number of permutation replicates
8. Compute the probability (p-value) of obtaining $\mu >= \mu_e $ from permutation replicates
9. Compare the p-value to $\alpha$

Is this method valid on time series, or do I need to use t-test?

Comment: See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/473076/permutation-tests-and-exchangeability/473108#473108