# Data Exchangebility of Maximum Likelihood Estimator

Tags: maximum-likelihood

Given i.i.d data $X_1, X_2, ..., X_n$ ~ certain distribution having certain parameter $\theta$, and we are then compute the maximum likelihood of $\theta$, namely $\theta_{MLE}$.

I'm just wondering, is $\theta_{MLE}$ invariant if we change the data order (permutate) for any distribution? My understanding so far tells me that it's always the case. But am i wrong ? is there a distribution on which this is not the case?

Answer (score 1):

By [exchangeability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exchangeable_random_variables) we mean

> Formally, an exchangeable sequence of random variables is a finite or
>   infinite sequence $X_1,X_2,\dots, X_n$ of random variables such that
>   for any finite permutation $\sigma$ of the indices $1, 2, 3, \dots$,
>   (the permutation acts on only finitely many indices, with the rest
>   fixed), the joint probability distribution of the permuted sequence
>
> $$ X_{\sigma(1)}, X_{\sigma(2)}, X_{\sigma(3)}, \dots $$
>
> is the same as the joint probability distribution of the original
>   sequence. In short, the order of the sequence of random variables does
>   not affect its joint probability distribution.

If you have a sequence of *[independent and identically distributed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independent_and_identically_distributed_random_variables)* random variables $X_1,X_2,\dots,X_n$, that say, each follow the distribution $f$, then by independence their joint distribution is

$$
g(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n) = \prod_{i=1}^n f(x_i)
$$

and since multiplication has the [commutative property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutative_property), so $a \times b = b \times a$, then obviously the distribution doesn't matter. Notice that this follows from independence alone, so they wouldn't even need to be identically distributed. Yet, [exchangeability does not require independence](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/3520/can-someone-explain-the-concept-of-exchangeability), so while it is related to the concept of i.i.d., they are not synonyms.